# How to handle form with expired token auto filled by browser?

Tags: php, webforms, token

My brand new oop-mvc-prg-token login form redirects after post. If you hit the back button the browser displays the form with autofilled values. On submit the front controller detects the stale form, displays a message like "Form not valid anymore" and the form with empty fields.

Is thats the way its supposed to be? Maybe its ok regarding prg but I'm not happy with the user experience. The Browser (even IE) should not autofill the form. Is the only solution randomizing field names?

How is the best pattern to handle the expired form?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe autocomlete="off" works. I you'll put this as form element attribute `<form autocomplete="off"></form>` This also disables browser autocomplete feature to suggest previously entered values..

Comment: Autocomplete is desired if the user starts to fill in values. The problem seems to be that the form is prefilled when the browser displays it from history cache. But no cache header I tried prevents that. Maybe I should do without session token?

Comment: No, it hasn't always todo with "when user types". It also disables password saving. If you put autocomplete="off" then browser wont ask you to save password neither autofill it. But did you try it?

Comment: Sure I tried. Though from security perspective disabling passwords saving is desirable the client doesnt like it - lack of convenience. I'll try displaying a message "Form expired" and a redirect after few seconds.